# 2.8 - Streched texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

im new using blender and I started to make a simple house with pixel art textures, the question is when i place the images appear stretched ¿is there any way to fix it? here some screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Show us your uv map in the UV Editor window.

Comment: The second image.